# What do you call the type of verb that by saying it you actually perform the action?

Tags: verbs

What do you call a verb that by saying it you actually perform the action?

Common example: Apologize -- "I apologize for hurting you." (You just apologized by saying that)

I vaguely remember hearing a specific term for this sort of verb once...

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are thinking of [performative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/performative).

Comment: Yes. That's the term Austin used in _How to Do Things With Words_. See also the [SIL linguistic glossary definition](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAPerformative.htm) and [Wikipedia on "Performativity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performativity).

Comment: @JohnLawler: Freddie Ayer (over-) used the adjective in his theories of language, and the OED has a 1922 citation. But Austin was probably the first to use it as a noun.

Comment: And the one that stuck, professionally. It had a profound effect on (then-nascent) transformational syntax.